# В чем проблема? Загрузил скрипт питона на хостинг. На ПК работает без проблем

Tags: python, бот, hosting

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На пк работает спокойно, загрузил на хостинг pythonanywhere, и вижу такую ошибку, с чем она связана?

**Тарифный план куплен!**

Comment: Нет связи с указанным айпи адресом с машины на которой вы запускаете, нет команды start(не знает сервер что делать с такой командой)

Comment: я понял что start нет, но как исправить ошибку?